# document.styleSheets[x].cssRules are null

Tags: css, stylesheet

When I inspect a website,
I see the cssRules from `document.styleSheets[x].cssRules`

[image]

However, with this website `stackoverflow.com`, when I inspect with Chrome browser, I see `document.styleSheets`, but `cssRules` is null.

[image]

How come this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the style sheets are coming from a different domain. Some browsers (such as Chrome) implement strict cross-domain policies by throwing security errors or setting the `cssRules` and `ownerRule` to null when it comes from a different domain...in your case the style sheets come from a CDN

MDN quotes the following in the `CSSStyleSheet` documentation...

> In some browsers, if a stylesheet is loaded from a different domain,
>   calling cssRules results in SecurityError.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: is there any known way of bypassing this problem? I mean, enforce the browser to fill the `cssRules` value? Maybe specifying a CORS option in the link tag?

Answer (score 2):

To try bypass this problem, you can add `crossorigin="anonymous"` in the link tag to prevent the error.

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

This will create a [potencial cors request](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#create-a-potential-cors-request) but the server must respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <authorized-domain>`.

You can check [here](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) to see how to add CORS support to your server.

For more information about CORS you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and [this](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol).