# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I wonder why does my script work on firefox but not on google chrome

JS:

```
var _timelineWidth = (Number.parseInt(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[16].style.width) / 100) * document.body.clientWidth;
```

CSS:

```
#timeline {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 12.5%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

here's the error code from chrome

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from
>   'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [External CSS styles cant be accessed in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472352/external-css-styles-cant-be-accessed-in-google-chrome)

Comment: The array index you referring may not be in the list. Please check that

Comment: Should use `getComputedStyle` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.styleSheets\[x\].cssRules are null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356349/document-stylesheetsx-cssrules-are-null)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In latest Chrome, **CORS** security rules are applicable for style-sheets also (Similar to Iframe rules).

You can load and render them but, cannot access the content through javascript (If loaded from Cross-Domain ).

If your CSS Stylesheet is from Same domain as of HTML /or included in same HTML file, you will be able to access `document.styleSheets[elem].cssRules`  otherwise it will throw error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
```

> Cross Domain Stylesheet

[image: Cross Domain Stylesheet]

> Same Domain Stylesheet

[image: Same Domain Stylesheet]

Comment: I'm using an external CSS, and haven't uploaded it anywhere, why it wouldn't work??

Comment: Check the URL.. Both html and stylesheet domain's must be same.. Be it localhost or filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for answer @AtulSharma Could you also suggest ways to access the content as well.

Comment: @anchal20 you cannot modify class from external stylesheet in Chrome. Though, you can make a copy of classes which needs modification to your main file or override them in your code thorough JS or directly manipulate the html elements.

Comment: @AtulSharma Shouldn't this be able to work on localhost? I have index.html and style.css in the same directory and I'm getting the error in Firefox. I don't remember seeing this error before today though so I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 27):

You can add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to prevent the error.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://..." crossorigin="anonymous">`

More info  here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

This will create a [potencial cors request](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#create-a-potential-cors-request) but the server must respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <authorized-domain>`.

You can check [here](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) to see how to add CORS support to your server.

For more information about CORS you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and [this](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol).

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't seem to actually work, at least in Chrome

Comment: @DanielMiller, you might be right. While it solved my problem, I guess with was dependent on the server response header. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I use Chrome, too, and add ``crossorigin="anonymous"`` indeed fixes my problem.

Comment: This does work, but I had a different approach in order to solve what I was trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327187/cannot-access-cssrules-for-stylesheet-cors/71327476#71327476

Comment: I had a problem when tried to access existing rules in js. I used this approach as well to fix it, but somehow it broke the stylesheet for some users, be cautious when deploying this fix

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and the answer `crossorigin="anonymous"` didn't fix it - because I wanted to *run things from the local file system!* Chrome's interpretation of CORS for local files are very strict. In this case you can forget about crossorigin="..." attributes, and *simply start Chrome with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`*

P.S.: No need to install a local testing server, as suggested elsewhere to a despairing front-end developer.