# Get element style before hover selector changes

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that finds the original background color of the pressed element.
I mean the background color that was **before** user hovered and the `:hover` selector (maybe) changed it.
I tried to use `document.styleSheets` but it [gives me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993633/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-read-the-cssrules-property).

**Example**

```js
window.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  pressedElement = e.target;
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(pressedElement,null).backgroundColor);
  //return blue but I want the background before hover changes (green,yellow,red in this case)
});
```

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
div:hover{
  background-color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:green;">1</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;">2</div>
<div style="background-color:red;">3</div>
```

`window.getComputedStyle(pressedElement,null).backgroundColor` return the current background color (blue in this case), but I want the background color before `:hover` changes (red, yellow or green in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the element with itself, which forces the hover state to update, then calculate the style:

```js
window.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  const target = e.target;
  target.parentNode.replaceChild(target, target)
  const color = window.getComputedStyle(target,null).backgroundColor;
  console.log(color);
  return color;
});
```

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
div:hover{
  background-color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:green;">1</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;">2</div>
<div style="background-color:red;">3</div>
```