# Cannot Access cssRules for Stylesheet CORS

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-s3, cors, cdn

So I've been reading that you can't access cssRules for external stylesheets because it runs into CORS policy issues.

I decided to take a different approach but I'm still running into issues.

My Approach:

1. Download the css files on the backend and upload them to S3 Bucket
2. Return back a existing link and new link for match purposes
3. Delete existing `link` tag and add in a new tag that will point to my CDN
4. Access `document.styleSheets`
5. Tadaaaa (but this fails)

What I'm trying to figure out is why am I still running into issues if my CDN allows access from any origin?

```
export default () => {
  const payload = [...document.styleSheets].filter(s => s.href).map(s => s.href);

  axios.post('SOME ENDPOINT', { css: payload }).then(({ status, data: { data: newLinks } }) => {
    if (status === 200) {
      for (const i in newLinks) {
        document.querySelector(`link[href="${newLinks[i].source}"]`).remove()
        const stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
        stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
        stylesheet.href = newLinks[i].downloaded;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
      }
    }
  }).then(() => {
    let delay = 250
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Stylesheets with Removed Links', [...document.styleSheets]);
    }, delay)
  }).then(() => {
    console.log([...document.styleSheets])
  })
}
```

[image: Stylesheets]

[image: S3 CORS]

Error on Safari `SecurityError: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet`

I have seen this link [Cannot access cssRules from local css file in Chrome 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753691/cannot-access-cssrules-from-local-css-file-in-chrome-64/49160760#49160760)

Result From Network Tab

[image: Network Request]

Comment: Doing `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet)` should trigger a request for that stylesheet.  Does that request look ok in the Network tab?

Comment: @James yup all of it looks good. Updated description with the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution...

All thanks to Paulo Belo from this link [Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993633/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-read-the-cssrules-property)

`stylesheet.crossOrigin = "anonymous"` solved my problem giving me access to the cssRules.

[image]
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

Note this fix does not work with existing stylesheets that are throwing this error.

`Exception: DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules at CSSStyleSheet.s`

This fix only works for your own uploaded sheets or in my case the ones from my CDN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For **ReactJS**,

1. Go to **public** folder
2. In **index.html** file, add `crossorigin="anonymous"` for css (**which is giving cross-origin error**)

Example:

[image]