# How can I recursively search all global variables for a string?

Tags: javascript, browser

On any modern website there are a lot of global variables of complex configuration. Some are simple strings or dates, some will be objects or arrays.

I want to search for the string `hello` to see if it is the value of any global variable, including nested properties/values.

For example, say this was a global variable:

```
nacho = {
    "a" : "one",
    "b" : [
        { "d" : "yes", "e" : "no" },
        { "d" : "alpha", "e" : "bravo" },
        { "d" : "hello", "e" : "bye" },
        { "d" : "charlie", "e" : "delta" },
    ],
    "c" : "two"
}
```

Then searching for `hello` should find `nacho.b[2].d`;

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did it go wrong? Please provide a minimal working example describing your problem, because we're not here to code FOR you.

Comment: But, to give you a start: `window` holds all globally scoped variables as properties. `for ... in` lets you iterate over properties of any object, and `object["property"]` allows you to dynamically access object properties by their names.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way you can do that regarding your specific example:

```js
// Global variable 1
const nacho = {
    "a": "one",
    "b": [
        { "d": "yes", "e": "no" },
        { "d": "alpha", "e": "bravo" },
        { "d": "hello", "e": "bye" },
        { "d": "charlie", "e": "delta" },
    ],
    "c": "two"
};

// Global variable 2
const foo = {
    "x": "foo",
    "y": {
        "z": "hello",
        "w": "world"
    }
};

// Global variable 3
const bar = {
    "items": [
        { "name": "apple", "color": "red" },
        { "name": "banana", "color": "yellow" },
        { "name": "hello", "color": "green" },
        { "name": "world", "color": "blue" }
    ],
    "count": 4
};

function searchInGlobals(obj, searchString, objName = '', path = [], visited = new Set()) {
    if (visited.has(obj)) { return; } // Check if we've already visited this object
    visited.add(obj); // Mark this object as visited
    for (const key in obj) {
        const value = obj[key];
        const newPath = [...path, key];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            try {
                searchInGlobals(value, searchString, objName, newPath, visited); // Recursive call to find everything
            } catch (error) {
                if (error instanceof DOMException && error.name === 'SecurityError') {
                    // Skip objects that throw a SecurityError (such as CSS stylesheets)
                    continue;
                } else {
                    throw error; // Rethrow if it's not the expected error
                }
            }
        } else if (typeof value === 'string' && value === searchString) {
            console.log(`${objName}${path.length > 0 ? '.' : ''}${newPath.join('.')}`);
        }
    }
}

function searchInAllGlobals(searchString) {
    const globalObject = window; // Assuming browser environment, change accordingly if using other environments
    for (const key in globalObject) {
        // Exclude known global objects (window, self, document, frames, global) as they repeat what we already have
        if (['window', 'self', 'document', 'frames', 'global'].includes(key)) {
            continue;
        }
        const value = globalObject[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            searchInGlobals(value, searchString, key);
        }
    }
}

// This is the function you can use
searchInAllGlobals('hello');
```

Note: a stack snippet was not working due to it being a sandboxed environment, this is because we are referencing the window object.

Comment: Don't use external links that can be broken, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Copy and pasting your code into Chrome developer console while on this page yields an error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules`.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan If you are trying to use that snippet on a website where you can't run the code on the server by direct access, you are limited by CORS. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994161/4544388

Comment: Humm. I am trying to search for a string in the JS memory when I'm on any arbitrary site.  The data is, there albeit obfuscated, since it's all client side. So I should be able to just search everything and find it, no?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I added error handling to my answer. It will skip anything that would throw a SecurityError. I tested it on StackOverflow and it gave outputs, so it is working.

Answer (score -1):

-> You can try this  Code :-

```
    function searchGlobalVariables(value, obj, path = []) {
    // Check if the current object is an array
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        // Iterate through the array elements
        obj.forEach((element, index) => {
            // Recursively search within each array element
            searchGlobalVariables(value, element, path.concat(index));
        });
    } else if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
        // If the current object is an object (non-null), iterate through its properties
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            // Recursively search within each property value
            searchGlobalVariables(value, val, path.concat(key));
        });
    } else if (obj === value) {
        // If the current value matches the search value, print the path to it
        console.log(`Found value "${value}" at ${path.join('.')}`);
    }
}

// Example global variable
nacho = {
    "a": "one",
    "b": [
        { "d": "yes", "e": "no" },
        { "d": "alpha", "e": "bravo" },
        { "d": "hello", "e": "bye" },
        { "d": "charlie", "e": "delta" },
    ],
    "c": "two"
};

// Search for the value "hello"
searchGlobalVariables("hello", window);
```

Comment: Copy and pasting your code into Chrome developer console while on this page yields an error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Answer (score -1):

First you should collect your globals, seems tricky.
Finding paths are easier, just use recursion:

```js
const walk = (obj,cb,path=[],foundObjects=new Set)=>{
    if(foundObjects.has(obj)) return; // avoid looking for the same objects (cross-referenced);
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        foundObjects.add(obj);
        obj.forEach((item,i)=>walk(item, cb, path.concat(i),foundObjects));
    } else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        foundObjects.add(obj);
        for (const k in obj) {
            walk(obj[k], cb, path.concat(k), foundObjects);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            cb(obj, path);
        }catch(e){}
    }
};

const paths = [];

const globals = {};

for (const k in window) {
    // only enumerables
    const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, k);
    if (!desc || typeof desc.value !== 'object' || !desc.configurable)
        continue;
    globals[k] = window[k];
}

walk(globals, (item,path)=>typeof item === 'string' && item.includes('hello') && paths.push(path));

console.log(paths.map(p=>p.map((n,i)=>typeof n === 'number' ? '[' + n + ']' : (i ? '.' : '') + n).join('')));
```

```html
<script>
nacho = {
    "a" : "one",
    "b" : [
        { "d" : "yes", "e" : "no" },
        { "d" : "alpha", "e" : "bravo" },
        { "d" : "hello", "e" : "bye" },
        { "d" : "charlie", "e" : "delta" },
    ],
    "c" : "two"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Strange, when I try it in the Chrome browser console, it gives range error.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan fixed, added a check for objects being parsed, works in chrome console for me

Comment: Strange. When I copy/paste the code into the dev console when on this SO question, I get an error "VM139:9 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules" at walk (<anonymous>:9:21)     at walk (<anonymous>:9:13)...

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you can add try/catch block, i will add later, in the bath, the solution is definitely working just needs some edge cases handled

Comment: Still getting an error. I'll debug this some more next weekend cause my wife is sick. `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules`